# Help needed with understanding the proof of "If $X'$ is separable, then $X$ is separable."

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

I may be forgetting something trivial here, but I don't follow (or understand the reasoning for) how the contradiction to the density of $(f_n)$ in $U'$ is achieved? I would like for someone to explain the last two sentences in the end in a little more detail, please.

Comment: @copper.hat: I'm sorry I forgot to do that. The above is from Erwin Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $A$ is dense in a metric space $(X,d)$,let $x \in X$ then every neighborhood (however small) of $x$ will intersect $A$.Can you complete now?

Comment: Yes, of course. I can do that now. I'd forgotten about this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dear @user264885, You're welcome!